# Compiling individual SASS files and "ignore" their includes or silence failed include errors

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I have some SCSS files, which look like below. I need to compile them individually. `mycorefile.css` will always be included first in a page, and then the others will be included if they are needed.

mycorefile.scss

```
.core {
  border:1px solid red;
  color:blue;
}
```

myextendingfile1.scss

```
@include mycorefile.scss
.extend1 {
  @extend .core;
  padding:20px;
}
```

myextendingfile2.scss

```
@include mycorefile.scss
.extend2 {
  @extend .core;
  float:left;
  width:150px;
}
```

myextendfile3.scss

```
@include mycorefile.scss
.extend3 {
  @extend .core;
  float:right;
  width:150px;
}
```

When including multiple extending files, the `.core` declaration is included on the page multiple times as well as the core file being present on the page; if all four files are compiled and included, there are four definitions of `.core`.

Is there a way to either make the compiler ignore the `@include` containing extends or make the compiler ignore/supress errors if the `@include` isn't present? Is there a custom Ruby way of doing it? Rewriting the way this currently works is not a favourable option.

Comment: @Sawa has deleted a key part through editing my question which is - The files are compiled out individually and used individually on the page, so I don't wish for any include to physically include class declarations in the compiled out file.

Comment: I had left a sentence "I need to compile them individually" as the second sentence.